# How do I remove extra Skype icon or ghost icons for removed apps from GNOME shell?

Tags: 18.04, icons, skype, gnome-shell, .desktop

When searching for "Skype" I always see these 2 entries.  There is this duplicate blank Skype icon. Both of them seem to run Skype in the same way.

[image: Skype icon screenshot]

But I've checked both `/usr/share/applications`, and `~/.local/share/applications`, and can't find the extra icon so I can delete it.

---

Also as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106912/uninstalled-applications-are-showing-empty-icon-with-their-name?noredirect=1), sometimes similar ghost icons are present even after removing associated applications.

Comment: Could it be one is snap install and the other is a deb install?

Comment: That's probably it.  Any idea what I can do about that? Software manager only shows one entry.  And I did keep my home partition from a previous Linux Mint install so that probably has something to do with it...

Comment: @Domarius That's a very important piece of info, you should have mentioned in your question. What are outputs of the following commands in Terminal: `apt policy skypeforlinux | grep Installed` and `snap list | grep -i skype`?

Comment: @pomsky I'm new to Linux though. As far as I was concerned, I did a full re-install from Linux Mint and kept my home drive, which should have only had user related settings, and program settings (not actual programs).  But  Alexandru's answer was the ticket!

Comment: might work for related problems: sudo apt-get install menulibre

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you have snap installed as per [your reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078736/how-do-i-remove-extra-skype-icon-from-gnome-shell#comment1772697_1078736) to @Carl's question.

Installing Skype from two sources (snap and .deb) lead to some junk `.desktop` files after removing the snap package. You can solve this by cleaning up after removing the snap.

Check the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory for a `skype_forlinux.desktop` file or something with `skype*` in the name (or any `.desktop` file which may be associated to the application). If you find it, move it somewhere else (e.g. `/tmp`) and check again by searching though '*Activities*'.

It should be fine now.

Comment: Thank you, that did it!  I guess since it's on the root file system, there's no way it's left around from the previous Linux Mint install I had.  If the only way it could have got there is from me installing Skype twice, then I'll have to accept that I somehow did that and forgot about it...

Comment: I had a handful of steam icons I removed from ~/.local/share/applications but the 'games' folder they all sat in still exists. Are there any other places these could be in?