# Uninstalled applications are showing empty icon with their name

Tags: uninstall, appmenu

So I had previously installed these and now I have uninstalled them but an empty icon with their name is generated and I want to remove it.

I tried right clicking and then show details but in software centre it is showing as uninstalled.

*Cannot add screen cast because of size limit*

Names of apps: **Coolreader3, Deadbeef**

[image: Screenshot of App menu]

Comment: Thanks it did the job. 
What to do with the question now? Should I remove the question or leave it.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Comment: It's just that, this question seems more general than skype one :(